# Is it possible to implement a socket server using either an Azure function or Azure Logic App?

Tags: sockets, azure, tcp, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I need to port an existing Azure Worker Role to either a Logic App or Azure function.  The Azure worker role includes a socket server that allows socket clients to connect and transmit data to the worker role for processing.  Can I get the same functionality (socket server) from either a logic app or function?

Comment: No, neither of these technologies support persistent connections